# Тестирование HttpURLConnection в Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

необходимо протестить метод `downloadFromUrl` на к-во вызовов `streamHelper.connectionStream(urlFile)`. Тест фейлится так как получаю null `NullPointerException` в строке `String httpUrl = httpURLConnection.getURL().toString();` медота `downloadFromUrl`, что в полне логично, так как `StreamHelperImpl` замоканный.

Подскажите как правильно протестить?

```
public String downloadFromUrl(String urlFile) {
    ....
    try {
       HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = streamHelper.connectionStream(urlFile);
        String httpUrl = httpURLConnection.getURL().toString();
        if (httpUrl.contains(propertiesLoader.getProperty(ConfigKeyNames.FILEMNG_ONEDRIVE_URL.name()))) {
            httpUrl = remadeLinkOneDriveDownload(httpUrl);
            httpURLConnection = streamHelper.connectionStream(httpUrl);
        }
       File file = createNewFileInTempDirectory(httpUrl);
        streamHelper.createConnectToFileStream(httpURLConnection, file);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.logError(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

тест

```
@Before
public void unit() {
    streamHelper = mock(StreamHelperImpl.class);
    propertiesLoader = injector.getInstance(PropertiesLoader.class);
    logger = injector.getInstance(Logger.class);
    fileManager = new FileManagerImpl(propertiesLoader, logger, streamHelper);
}


@Test
public void callStreamHelper_connectionStream_DirectUrl() throws Exception{

    when(fileManager.downloadFromUrl(directUrl)).thenReturn(anyString());
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
    when(streamHelper.connectionStream(directUrl)).thenReturn(httpURLConnection);
    verify(streamHelper, times(1)).connectionStream(directUrl);

}
```

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы замокать значение, возвращаемое из `connectionStream()`? И вообще подумать о том, нужны ли вам на самом деле юнит-тесты на этот класс/метод или достаточно протестировать его один раз руками/написать smoke-тест?

Comment: метод надо покрыть тестами по 5-7 параметрам и без тестов никак. Все коннекшены и стримы целенаправлено вынес в отдельный класс StreamHelper что бы сделать этот метод тестабл

Comment: *"Все коннекшены и стримы целенаправлено вынес в отдельный класс StreamHelper"* -- это хорошо, но как насчет самого `HttpURLConnection`? Его методы тоже надо мокать.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Arrange
    URL urlDirectDrive = new URL(url);
    when(streamHelper.createFile(anyString())).thenReturn(file);

    when(propertiesLoader.getProperty(ConfigKeyNames.FILEMNG_ONEDRIVE_URL.name())).thenReturn(ONEDRIVE_LIVE);
    when(propertiesLoader.getProperty(ConfigKeyNames.FILEMNG_DEFAULT_NAME_FILE.name())).thenReturn(anyString());
    when(streamHelper.getConnectionStreamForFileUrl(url)).thenReturn(httpURLConnection);
    when(httpURLConnection.getURL()).thenReturn(urlDirectDrive);

    //Act
    fileManager.downloadFromUrl(urlRedirect);

    //Assert
    verify(streamHelper, times(2)).getConnectionStreamForFileUrl(anyString());
}
```